# Execv with files in a child process

Tags: c, execv

I have two programs in the same directory main and example, if I execute `./example file.txt` it manages simple tasks with that file. Then my main program is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
   pid_t const pid1 = fork();
   if(pid1==0){
     execv();
   }
   else{
     wait(NULL);
   }
 }
```

So I want to execute `./main file.txt` and the child process should execute `./example file.txt` with the same file that main has received in argv[1].
My question is how to use the execv parameters to accomplish this.
Sorry if I did not explained myself simple.
Thank You

Comment: Please just show [minimum necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Give me 5 mins to modify the question, thanks.

Comment: @PCLuddite There you have my modified question. Sorry for that

Comment: @melpomene There you have my modified question. Sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
execl("./example", "example", argv[1], (char *)NULL);
```

Alternatively,

```
char *args[] = {
    "example",
    argv[1],
    NULL
};
execv("./example", args);
```